# How to get a RadioButton to work

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to get my RadioButton to work and return something. Well to be a bit clearer I want it to go something like this. The user select 2 Joueur or 3 Joueur, next select Sans or Avec and then press the Jouer Button and the program swift to the next window, but can't figure out how. Here the code im working with at the moment.

My program is a PokerDice game using tkinter as interface. Im French so thats why the variable are all in French.

Thanks for your help in advance

```
class PokerDice(Tk):
def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)

    programme = Frame()
    programme.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    programme.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
    programme.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5)

    self.pages = {}
    for unePage in (DebuterProgramme, PageInstructions, PartiesDePoker, LancerParties):
        page_de_demarrage = unePage(programme, self)
        self.pages[unePage] = page_de_demarrage
        page_de_demarrage.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.voir_pages(DebuterProgramme)

def voir_pages(self, cont):
    voir_page_de_demarrage = self.pages[cont]
    voir_page_de_demarrage.tkraise()


class DebuterProgramme(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Poker D'As", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    button_instructions = Button(self, text="Instructions",
                                 command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(PageInstructions))
    button_instructions.pack()

    button_jouer = Button(self, text="Jouer",
                          command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(PartiesDePoker))
    button_jouer.pack()

    button_jouer = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=quit)
    button_jouer.pack()


class PageInstructions(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Instructions", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, pady=10, padx=10)
    var = StringVar()
    text = Message(self, textvariable=var, font=NORMAL_FONT)
    var.set("\n1. Vous devez choisir le nombres de joueurs pour la partie."
            "\n\n2. Vous devez choisir si les AS sont des jokers ( dés frimés )."
            "\n\n3. Losque la partie seras debute vous devez inscrire les noms "
            "des joueurs dans les cases respectives."
            "\n\n4. Le premier joueur lanceras les dés un maximum de 3 fois,"
            " le deuxième joueurs auras le même nombres de lancers que le joueur 1."
            " Il est avantangeux d'être le premier a jouer."
            "\n\n5. "
            "\n\n6. Vous devez inscrire les changements de dés de cette façon. "
            "exemple : 1,2,3 ou appuyer sur la touche [ENTER] pour relancer aucun dés"
            "\n\n7. Le but du jeu de Poker D'AS est d'avoir les meilleurs combinaisons de dés possibles."
            "\n\n8. Voici une liste des meilleurs combinaisons de dés possible en ordre"
            "décroissant."
            "\n\nQuinton (5 dés même valeur)"
            "\n\nCarre (4 dés de même valeur)"
            "\n\nFull (3 dés de même valeur et une paire)"
            "\n\nBrelan (3 dés de même valeur)"
            "\n\nSequence (soit du dés 9 a ROI ou 10 a AS )"
            "\n\nDeux paires (2 dés de même valeur + 2 dés de même valeur)"
            "\n\nUne Paire (2 dés de même valeur)"
            "\n\n")
    text.pack()

    button_retour = Button(self, text="Retour", command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(DebuterProgramme))
    button_retour.pack()


class PartiesDePoker(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = Label(self, text="Vous voulez combien de joueurs ? ", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    button_joueur2 = Radiobutton(self, text="2 Joueurs", command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(LancerParties))
    button_joueur2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    button_joueur3 = Radiobutton(self, text="3 Joueurs")
    button_joueur3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    label = Label(self, text="Voulez-vous jouer sans frimes ou avec frimes ?", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    button_oui = Radiobutton(self, text="Sans")
    button_oui.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
    button_non = Radiobutton(self, text="Avec")
    button_non.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    button_retour = Button(self, text="Retour", command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(DebuterProgramme))
    button_retour.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    button_jouer = Button(self, text="Jouer", command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(LancerParties))
    button_jouer.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class LancerParties(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    label_joueur_1 = Label(self, text="Joueur # 1")
    label_joueur_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    nom_joueur_1 = Entry(self)
    nom_joueur_1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    label_joueur_2 = Label(self, text="Joueur # 2")
    label_joueur_2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    nom_joueur_2 = Entry(self)
    nom_joueur_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    label_joueur_3 = Label(self, text="Joueur # 3")
    label_joueur_3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    nom_joueur_3 = Entry(self)
    nom_joueur_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    button_lancer_partie = Button(self, text="Lancer la partie",
                                  command=lambda: controller.voir_pages(DebutDeLaPartie))
    button_lancer_partie.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class DebutDeLaPartie(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
pass
```

pokerAs = PokerDice()
pokerAs.mainloop()

Comment: It will be helpful for others if you provide the information of what your current code does and what issues you are facing with it.

Comment: Please make sure to have read and understood [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem. Your `Radiobutton`s are not connected and you have no way to read their status. Create a `Variable` and use that for all `Radiobutton`s in the group.

Code from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm):

```
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W)
```

So `var` represents the status of the button group. Each button is given a different value so that you can tell which is selected.

Note that each group will need it's own `IntVar`. And make sure to keep a reference to the variable by assigning it to an instance variable (i.e. `self.var`)

When you want to check the status you use `var.get()`.

Comment: awesome ill try that right now ! Quick question what is the command=sel do ?

Comment: That is similar to the `command` argument to buttons. It registers a callback for when the state of the variable changes. You should not need to use that.

Comment: So when I select it I can't delete right ? lets say I click on it on the interface once its selected I can re-click on it to deselect it right ?

Comment: Generally Radiobuttons have to have one option in the group selected. The normal way to accomplish what you describe would be to have a "None" option.