# how to use radiobuttons on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I want to make a program that can define a variable using radiobuttons but I don't really know how the values of them works.. I have something like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("1366x768+0+0")

var_gender=IntVar()
selectGender1= Radiobutton(root,text="Male",variable= var_gender,value=1)
selectGender2= Radiobutton(root, text="Female",variable= var_gender,value=2)

seleccionGenero.place(x=500,y=350)
seleccionGenero2.place(x=700,y=350)

if var_gender=="1":
   genderUser="Male"
else:
   genderUser="Female"
```

but it doesn't save any value on `genderUser`, so I think this isn't the way the value on radiobuttons works...

Comment: This question shows no signs of research, for something that is fairly well documented. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a RadioButton to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218625/how-to-get-a-radiobutton-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from an IntVar you have to use the `.get()` method:

And then you would typically want to assign a callback function to your Radiobuttons to catch any changes.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x200+1000+50")

def radio_get():   # Radiobutton callback function.
    if var_gender.get() == 1:
       genderUser = "Male"
    else:
       genderUser = "Female"
    print(genderUser)

var_gender=IntVar()
selectGender1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Male", variable=var_gender,
                            value=1, command=radio_get)
selectGender2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Female", variable=var_gender,
                            value=2, command=radio_get)

selectGender1.place(x=50,y=50)
selectGender2.place(x=50,y=70)
```